# Як назвати два боки диплома

Tags: вибір-слова

Як називаються два боки диплома чи іншого документу?

[image]

Comment: Які ваші варіанти, чим не подобаються ті що ви знайшли?

Comment: Наприклад, бачив варіанти (для "першої" сторінки): лицева сторона або титульна сторона. Для іншої сторони - зворотна сторона. Один з варіантів був "тильна сторона", але той, хто це використовував вважав що це синонім для "лицевої сторони", хоча на мій погляд "тильна" це якраз зворотна.

Comment: Хоч мені не дуже подобається запитання, тобто відсутність спроб автора відшукати варіанти відповіді, та все ж дам коментар. [Наказ Міністерства освіти і науки України від 04 лютого 2014 року № 97 "Про затвердження технічних описів документів про освіту та вчені звання"](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0283-14) - ***лицьовий бік (титульна сторінка)*** vs ***зворотний бік (текстуальна сторінка)***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хоч мені не дуже подобається запитання, тобто відсутність спроб автора відшукати варіанти відповіді, втім.

Наказ Міністерства освіти і науки України від 04 лютого 2014 року № 97 ["Про затвердження технічних описів документів про освіту та вчені звання"](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0283-14) - **`лицьовий бік`** (***`титульна сторінка`***) vs ***`зворотний бік`*** (***`текстуальна сторінка`***).

> ТЕХНІЧНІ ОПИСИ документів про освіту, що виготовляються на основі
>   фотокомп’ютерних технологій
>
> І. Технічний опис свідоцтва про базову загальну середню освіту, що
>   виготовляється на основі фотокомп’ютерних технологій
>
> <..>
>
> 2. Загальний вигляд **лицьового боку (титульної сторінки)** картки:
>
> по периметру зроблено художнє графічне обрамлення у вигляді віньєтки
>   зеленого кольору;
>
> у верхній частині картки розміщене зображення малого Державного Герба
>   України, під ним посередині розташовано напис «УКРАЇНА» літерами
>   зеленого кольору; нижче - напис «СВІДОЦТВО» літерами зеленого кольору,
>   під ним - «про базову загальну середню освіту» літерами зеленого
>   кольору;
>
> під нижньою лінією рамки в правій частині картки зеленою фарбою
>   надруковано вихідні реквізити: «Зам. № (рік виконання замовлення)».
>
> 3. Загальний вигляд **зворотного боку (текстуальної сторінки)** картки:
>
> у верхній та нижній частинах картки розміщено художнє графічне
>   обрамлення у вигляді віньєтки зеленого кольору; у верхній частині
>   картки посередині розташовано напис «СВІДОЦТВО» літерами зеленого
>   кольору, під ним посередині відтворено чорною фарбою текстову
>   інформацію відповідно до зразка, затвердженого у встановленому
>   законодавством порядку;
>
> у лівому нижньому куті зроблено художнє візерункове обрамлення у
>   вигляді віньєтки зеленого кольору, посередині якої розміщена
>   прямокутна рамка розміром 28x5 мм для друку серії, що складається з
>   двох літер, і номера свідоцтва, що складається з восьми цифр; серія та
>   номер відтворені чорною фарбою.